# Navigation action destination is not being registered

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I have a simple project with 3 fragments and i'm trying to add animations to it transitions.
It navigates when i click the buttons but now i'm trying to add animations to those transitions in the nav graph but for some reason the destination of the actions are not being registered.
This is the code i have already:

Main Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setupActionBarWithNavController(findNavController(R.id.fragment))
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
```

Fragment A:

```
class FragmentA : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentABinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentABinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val navController : NavController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
        binding.button1.setOnClickListener {
            navController.navigate(R.id.fragmentB)
        }

        binding.button2.setOnClickListener {
            navController.navigate(R.id.fragmentC)
        }
    }
}
```

Main activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment A xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
    tools:context="com.example.FragmentA">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/fragmentB"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/fragmentC"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And the other 2 fragments just have 2 buttons and nothing of logic aplicated yet.
So when i try to create an action for the navigation from Fragment A (Home fragment) to fragment B the desing  window normally shows the id of the action and its destinantion but i don't know why it is not registering the destination when i create the action. It looks like this now:

[image]

I tried to add the destination manually but it doesn't works either because it just delete it and let it blank again.

Nav Graph xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragmentA">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
        android:name="com.example.FragmentA"
        android:label="fragment_a"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_a" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragmentA_to_fragmentB2"
            app:destination="@id/fragmentB" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
        android:name="com.example.FragmentB"
        android:label="fragment_b"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_b" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentC"
        android:name="com.example.FragmentC"
        android:label="fragment_c"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_c" />
</navigation>
```

Animation xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%" android:duration ="800"/>

</set>
```

I added this custom animation to enterAnim field but its not taking it.
I don't really know whats going on and i didn't find any answer to this issue.

Comment: That's nothing to worry about, Its some kinda bug ig, just click on the field and the `destination` will be visible. Check the `nav_graph.xml`, the `destination` attribute is right there under `action`

Comment: The problem is that when i apply my animation it doesn't play it and i think that's why. Because it registers the enterAnim for example but not the destination.

Comment: I suggest you to upload your animation code too, might help you in debugging your error quicker

Comment: I edited my question and added it @rcs

Comment: I don't see any problem, if you have used only 'enter'  or 'exit'  anim, it may be hard to visualize.

Comment: try using both 'enter'  and 'exit' anim and check the [offical doc] (https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/animate)  for more info

Comment: The thing is it doesn't shows any animation even the default ones are not working. And the destination field is bugged. Don't know what is wrong to be honest. @rcs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error and it was on the Fragmnet A code. It was about the click listener.
I had it like:

```
        binding.button1.setOnClickListener {
            navController.navigate(R.id.fragmentB)
        }
```

but i need to add the action instead:

```
binding.button1.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fragmentA_to_fragmentB)
        }
```

The destination field is bugged i think, now everything works as it should.